# Rails asset pipeline vs static asset load speed difference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, asset-pipeline

I tested the load times of the same asset twice. One under the rails asset pipeline (/app/assets/javascripts) and the other as a static file (/public).

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' -%>
<script src='/application.js'></script>
```

Heres what I got:
[image] 
What's causing this magnitude of difference between the files when they're about the same size? How can I speed up the load time of a static asset which is 10x slower than if it was in the asset pipeline?

Comment: Did you try reversing the order and seeing if it looks the same? Caching sometimes causes weird magnitudes of differences between identical resources, and while I don't think that's your issue here, it should be ruled out.

Comment: Indeed it was not the issue, but thank you for the reminder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated to rack 1.6.4, solved this issue. Looks like rack 1.6.0 introduced  `options[:OutputBufferSize] = 5`

Source: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18828